# Whether $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n n^2}{n^2+5} =\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-1\right)^n -\dfrac{5}{n^2+5} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n n^2}{n^2+5} =\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(-1\right)^n -\dfrac{5}{n^2+5} $$

I don't trust my solution, mostly because I don't have much experience with using $\left(-1\right)^n$.

Because both summations have the same starting point ($1$) and ending point ($\infty$). Thus $a_n = b_n$.

$$\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n n^2}{n^2+5} = \left(-1\right)^n - \dfrac{5}{n^2+5} $$

$$\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n n^2}{n^2+5} + \dfrac{5}{n^2+5} = \left(-1\right)^n  $$

$$ \left(-1\right)^n\dfrac{n^2+5}{n^2+5} = \left(-1\right)^n$$

$$ \dfrac{n^2+5}{n^2+5} = \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(-1\right)^n} $$

$$ 1 = 1 $$

Comment: I guess you miss $(-1)^n$ for the last term on the first step

Comment: In general, you can't conclude that each $a_n=b_n$ simply on the basis that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$. You can't even conclude that *any* $a_n=b_n$. For example, let $$a_n=\begin{cases}2^{-(n+1)/2} & \text{if }n\text{ is odd,}\\0 & \text{if }n\text{ is even,}\end{cases}$$ and let $$b_n=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }n\text{ is odd,}\\2^{-n/2} & \text{if }n\text{ is even.}\end{cases}$$ Then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n,$$ but $a_n\neq b_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Great counter example!

Comment: Glad you liked it.

Comment: Of course, if we can show that $a_n=b_n$ for all $n$, then it certainly follows that $\sum a_n=\sum b_n$.

Comment: I don't know what the question is. The infinite sum you start with **does not converge**.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was wondering if my rewritting was correct, still trying to get a deep and clear understanding of series.  I was worried about the $(-1)^n$, but fan and Avatar show me where I made a mistake and Cameron Buie gave me some deeper understanding with a great counter example.

Comment: The rewriting happened to be wrong, but since the sum doesn't exist, you should not have been manipulating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n n^2}{n^2+5} =  \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n ((n^2+5)-5)}{n^2+5} = \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n (n^2+5)}{(n^2+5)} -  \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n 5}{n^2+5} $$ $$=(-1)^n- \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^n 5}{n^2+5} $$

You missed $(-1)^n$ on R.H.S. with $5$ in numerator.